# Optimized version of grep to match vector against vector

Tags: r, regex, optimization, vector

Suppose I have two vectors of characters `a` and `b`:

```
set.seed(123)
categ <- c("Control", "Gr", "Or", "PMT", "P450")
genes <- paste(categ, rep(1:40, each=length(categ)), sep="_")
a0 <- paste(genes, "_", rep(1:50, each=length(genes)), "_", sep="")
b0 <- paste (a0, "1", sep="")
ite <- 200
lg <- 2000
b <- b0[1:lg]
a <- (a0[1:lg])[sample(seq(lg), ite)]
```

I want to apply the `grep` function in order to find the match of each value of `a` in `b`.
Of course I could do:

```
sapply(a, grep, b)
```

but I wonder if there is something more efficient as I will have to run this a lot of times for much larger vectors in simulations (note that I don't want to use `mclapply` either as I already use it to run each iteration of my simulations):

```
system.time(lapply(seq(100000), function(x) sapply(a, grep, b)))
library(parallel)
system.time(mclapply(seq(100000), function(x) sapply(a, grep, b), mc.cores=8))
```

Comment: Is there always at most a single match? If so `pmatch(a, b)` sounded like a good suggestion.

Comment: You could also use exact matches after removing the last two characters of the `b` items if it is appropriate: `match(a, substr(b, 1L, nchar(b) - 2L))`. You'd have to try on your large data to see what is faster.

Comment: Thanks flodel. My example is a bit specific but I'd like a general solution. So first, `pmatch` will definitively helps for cases where there is only a single match. Then, here the 2 last letters of the `b` are uninformative but this might not be always the case.

Comment: How large are your two vectors in the worst case?

Comment: This will reduce it to a single `grep`: `grep(paste(a, collapse = "|"), b)`

Comment: When there is a match between `a[i]` and `b[j]`, does it always mean that `identical(a[i], substr(b[j], 1, nchar(a[i]))`? In other words, you would only need to look for a match at the beginning of the `b` strings? If not, please make your example as general as possible, including multiple matches and mid-string matches.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck. This is answering a different question, no?

Comment: @flodel, It gives a similar answer to `sapply(a, grep, b)` but runs faster.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: You are answering "what `b` items are found in `a`". He is asking that for each `a` item we provide the indices of the matching items in `b`. His most general output will be a list of same length as `a`.

Comment: @LudoDuvaux Maybe you should remove `sapply(a,grep,b)` from the question since it don't give all the occurrence(matches) of a in b.

Comment: @flodel-1: no more than dozen of thousands values, so short vectors should be good.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: interesting idea but this gives me results different from what I expect (i.e. different from `sapply(a, grep, b)`), and thus let room for bugs :s

Comment: @agstudy: no, `sapply(a,grep,b)` does exactly what I want contrary to `grep(paste(a, collapse = "|"), b)`.

Comment: @flodel-2: for that problem in particular, it is but I was also wondering about more general cases. You guys have give me pretty good insights though.

Comment: Then I would suggest you try `lapply(paste0("^", a), grep, b)`. Adding the `^` at the front will allow grep to rule out matches as soon as the first character(s) in a `b` item does not match those found in the `a` item. That being said, what you are asking for requires that `length(a) * length(b)` comparisons be made, which will take a lot of time regardless.

Comment: How about `ix <- sapply(paste(a, collapse = "|"), grep, b); bix <- b[ix]; sapply(a, grep, bix)` so that the `sapply` only operates on the smaller `bix`.

Comment: Following that size reduction idea, he could split `a` and `b` by the first few characters or the first word until the first underscore: "Or", "Gr", "Control", "PMT", etc. Then only look for matches in corresponding sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested out  on my own data the different solutions proposed by @flodel and @Sven Hohenstein (Note that @Martin Morgan's method cannot be tested for the moment as it doesn't support when elements of `a` that are prefix of other elements of `a`).

***IMPORTANT NOTE: altough all methods give the same result in my specific case, remind that they all have their own way, and thus can give different results depending on the structure of the data***

Here is a quick summary (the results are shown below):

1. In my tests, `length(a)` and `length(b)` are set to 200 or 400 and 2,000 or 10,000 respectively
2. there is only a single match of each value of `a` in `b`
3. the best method **really depends of the problem and all deserves to be tested for each specific cases**
4. `pmatch` always performs very well (notably for small length of vectors `a` and `b`, say less than 100 and 1,000 respectively - not shown below),
5. `sapply(a, grep, b, fixed=T)` and `reduced.match` (flodel's method) functions always perform better than `sapply(a, grep, b))` and `sapply(paste0("^", a), grep, b)`.

***Here is the reproductible code along with the results of the tests***

```
# set up the data set
library(microbenchmark)
categ <- c("Control", "Gr", "Or", "PMT", "P450")
genes <- paste(categ, rep(1:40, each=length(categ)), sep="_")
a0 <- paste(genes, "_", rep(1:50, each=length(genes)), "_", sep="")
b0 <- paste (a0, "1", sep="")

# length(a)==200 & length(b)==2,000
ite <- 200
lg <- 2000
b <- b0[1:lg]
a <- (a0[1:lg])[sample(seq(lg), ite)]

microbenchmark(as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b)),                 # original
               as.vector(sapply(paste0("^", a), grep, b)),  # @flodel 1
               as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b, fixed = TRUE)), # Sven Hohenstein
               unlist(reduced.match(a, b)), # @ flodel 2
#~               f3(a, b), @Martin Morgan
               pmatch(a, b))

Unit: milliseconds
                                        expr        min         lq     median
               as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b)) 188.810585 189.256705 189.827765
  as.vector(sapply(paste0("^", a), grep, b)) 157.600510 158.113507 158.560619
 as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b, fixed = TRUE))  23.954520  24.109275  24.269991
                 unlist(reduced.match(a, b))   7.999203   8.087931   8.140260
                                pmatch(a, b)   7.459394   7.489923   7.586329
         uq        max neval
 191.412879 222.131220   100
 160.129008 186.695822   100
  25.923741  26.380578   100
   8.237207  10.063783   100
   7.637560   7.888938   100


# length(a)==400 & length(b)==2,000
ite <- 400
lg <- 2000
b <- b0[1:lg]
a <- (a0[1:lg])[sample(seq(lg), ite)]

microbenchmark(as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b)),                 # original
               as.vector(sapply(paste0("^", a), grep, b)),  # @flodel 1
               as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b, fixed = TRUE)), # Sven Hohenstein
               unlist(reduced.match(a, b)), # @ flodel 2
#~               f3(a, b), @Martin Morgan
               pmatch(a, b))

Unit: milliseconds
                                        expr       min        lq    median
               as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b)) 376.85638 379.58441 380.46107
  as.vector(sapply(paste0("^", a), grep, b)) 314.38333 316.79849 318.33426
 as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b, fixed = TRUE))  49.56848  51.54113  51.90420
                 unlist(reduced.match(a, b))  13.31185  13.44923  13.57679
                                pmatch(a, b)  15.15788  15.24773  15.36917
        uq       max neval
 383.26959 415.23281   100
 320.92588 346.66234   100
  52.02379  81.65053   100
  15.56503  16.83750   100
  15.45680  17.58592   100


# length(a)==200 & length(b)==10,000
ite <- 200
lg <- 10000
b <- b0[1:lg]
a <- (a0[1:lg])[sample(seq(lg), ite)]

microbenchmark(as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b)),                 # original
               as.vector(sapply(paste0("^", a), grep, b)),  # @flodel 1
               as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b, fixed = TRUE)), # Sven Hohenstein
               unlist(reduced.match(a, b)), # @ flodel 2
#~               f3(a, b), @Martin Morgan
               pmatch(a, b))

Unit: milliseconds
                                        expr       min        lq    median
               as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b)) 975.34831 978.55579 981.56864
  as.vector(sapply(paste0("^", a), grep, b)) 808.79299 811.64919 814.16552
 as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b, fixed = TRUE)) 119.64240 120.41718 120.73548
                 unlist(reduced.match(a, b))  34.23893  34.56048  36.23506
                                pmatch(a, b)  37.57552  37.82128  38.01727
        uq        max neval
 986.17827 1061.89808   100
 824.41931  854.26298   100
 121.20605  151.43524   100
  36.57896   43.33285   100
  38.21910   40.87238   100



# length(a)==400 & length(b)==10500
ite <- 400
lg <- 10000
b <- b0[1:lg]
a <- (a0[1:lg])[sample(seq(lg), ite)]

microbenchmark(as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b)),                 # original
               as.vector(sapply(paste0("^", a), grep, b)),  # @flodel 1
               as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b, fixed = TRUE)), # Sven Hohenstein
               unlist(reduced.match(a, b)), # @ flodel 2
#~               f3(a, b), @Martin Morgan
               pmatch(a, b))

Unit: milliseconds
                                        expr        min         lq     median
               as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b)) 1977.69564 2003.73443 2028.72239
  as.vector(sapply(paste0("^", a), grep, b)) 1637.46903 1659.96661 1677.21706
 as.vector(sapply(a, grep, b, fixed = TRUE))  236.81745  238.62842  239.67875
                 unlist(reduced.match(a, b))   57.18344   59.09308   59.48678
                                pmatch(a, b)   75.03812   75.40420   75.60641
         uq        max neval
 2076.45628 2223.94624   100
 1708.86306 1905.16534   100
  241.12830  283.23043   100
   59.76167   88.71846   100
   75.99034   90.62689   100
```

Comment: If people are happy with my summary, I'll tick it as definitive answer. So please let me know

Comment: It's not helpful to use mclapply for the faster methods, which you can show for yourself by using lapply instead (e.g., for f3 100 replicates under mclapply is _slower_ than with lapply). If you're trying to get replicate observations, then use the microbenchmark (or other) package maybe just with the 'fast' methods since it's clear that the grep solution is polynomial whereas the others are closer to linear. Be sure to provide a reproducible way to generate your sample (a, b) data, as @flodel does.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Ok, I'll try to provide reproductible sample and to redo the tests when I'll have some time. However, it might be interesting to see how each function interact with mclapply as people may want to use the function a very short script that will be run many times. No?

Answer (score 8):

Since you don't use regular expressions but want to find substrings in longer strings, you can use `fixed = TRUE`. It is much faster.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(lapply(a, grep, b),                 # original
                 lapply(paste0("^", a), grep, b),  # @flodel
                 lapply(a, grep, b, fixed = TRUE))

Unit: microseconds
                             expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
               lapply(a, grep, b) 112.633 114.2340 114.9390 116.0990 326.857   100
  lapply(paste0("^", a), grep, b) 119.949 121.7380 122.7425 123.9775 191.851   100
 lapply(a, grep, b, fixed = TRUE)  21.004  22.5885  23.8580  24.6110  33.608   100
```

---

Testing with longer vectors (1000 times the original length).

```
ar <- rep(a, 1000)
br <- rep(b, 1000)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(lapply(ar, grep, br),               # original
               lapply(paste0("^", ar), grep, br),  # @flodel
               lapply(ar, grep, br, fixed = TRUE))

Unit: seconds
                               expr       min        lq    median       uq       max neval
               lapply(ar, grep, br) 32.288139 32.564223 32.726149 32.97529 37.818299   100
  lapply(paste0("^", ar), grep, br) 24.997339 25.343401 25.531138 25.71615 28.238802   100
 lapply(ar, grep, br, fixed = TRUE)  2.461934  2.494759  2.513931  2.55375  4.194093   100
```

(This took quite a while...)

Comment: I'm surprised `fixed` is so much faster when there are no "wildcards" in the regular expression.

Comment: Well, for my specific example, using `pmatch` as suggested by flodel (in a comment of the question) was by far the more efficient. However, for general purpose your above solution is great and for very long vectors, the formal reply of flodel deserves to be tested as well. I think I'll try to summarize all this in an answer of mine if you're OK with that.

Answer (score 3):

Following on my last suggestion...

The big problem with what you are asking is that, a priori, you need to do `length(a) * length(b)` comparisons. However, you can take advantage of the fact that the matches here will only happen at the beginning of the strings (what I gathered from the comments.).

I suggested you first split your `a` and `b` vectors into lists, after looking at the first word ( "Or", "Gr", "Control", "PMT", etc.) in each item, then only look for matches in the corresponding sets. In other words, take the items in `a` that start with `Or_` and only look for matches in the items in `b` that also start with `Or_`.

To give you an idea of why this is efficient in terms of complexity. Imagine `a` and `b` both have length `n`; that there are `x` possible prefixes, uniformly distributed throughout `a` and `b`. Then you would only have to do `x * (n/x * n/x)` comparisons versus `n * n` in your case. That's `x` times fewer comparisons. And you could even imagine repeating the process using the second word, third, etc. in a recursive way.

Now here is the code for it:

```
reduced.match <- function(a, b) {

   first.word <- function(string) sub("_.*", "", string)

   a.first <- first.word(a)
   b.first <- first.word(b)
   l.first <- unique(c(a.first, b.first))
   a.first <- factor(a.first, l.first)
   b.first <- factor(b.first, l.first)
   a.split <- split(a, a.first)
   b.split <- split(b, b.first)
   a.idx.split <- split(seq_along(a), a.first)
   b.idx.split <- split(seq_along(b), b.first)

   unsorted.matches <-
     Map(function(a, b, i) lapply(a, function(x) i[grep(x, b, fixed = TRUE)]),
         a.split, b.split, b.idx.split, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

   sorted.matches <-
     unlist(unsorted.matches, recursive = FALSE)[
       match(seq_along(a), unlist(a.idx.split))]

   return(sorted.matches)
}
```

---

```
# sample data
set.seed(123)
n <- 10000
words <- paste0(LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS)
a <- paste(sample(words[-1], n, TRUE),
           sample(words, n, TRUE), sep = "_")
b <- paste(sample(words[-2], n, TRUE),
           sample(words, n, TRUE), sep = "_")

# testing
identical(reduced.match(a, b), lapply(a, grep, b, fixed = TRUE))
# [1] TRUE

# benchmarks
system.time(reduced.match(a, b))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.187   0.000   0.187 
system.time(lapply(a, grep, b, fixed = TRUE))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.915   0.002   2.920
```

Comment: Well, for my specific example, using `pmatch` as you suggested in your comment was the more efficient. However, for general purpose Sven's solution is great and for very long vectors, your formal reply deserves to be tested as well. I think I'll try to summarize all this in an answer of mine if you're OK with that.

Comment: Sure feel free. I'm hoping you will test our methods on your own data and report timings.

Comment: I tested the 5 different methods I could (see below, I couldn't test Martin's as it doesn't support that some elements of ```a``` being prefix of other elements of ```a```). In my specific case, using ```pmatch``` was the most efficient, but depending on the situation it might be better to use ```reduce.match```. What do you think is the best answer to quote as accepted answer thus? Mine where I compare all methods or would you like to write a formal answer saying that I should use ```pmatch``` and then quote this one as accepted? not sure about the best habit to get on Stackoverflow.

Comment: no stress, picking the accepted answer is a personal and subjective matter. some people go by who got the most votes, who has been the most helpful, who got the fastest code, etc. All the answers you got were correct and on target so you can pick anyone of them and nobody will feel offended.

Comment: thanks, I'll pick up mine thus as it summarizes results of all proposed solutions (people could see below if the said method interest them).

Answer (score 3):

If a and b are sorted (and a unique) and one is interested in exact matches at the beginning of the string, then the following C code will usually be relatively efficient (something on the order of length(a) + length(b) string comparisons?). The R wrapper makes sure the C code and R user get appropriate data.

```
f3 <- local({
    library(inline)
    .amatch <- cfunction(c(a="character", b="character"),
             includes="#include <string.h>", '
         int len_a = Rf_length(a), len_b = Rf_length(b);
         SEXP ans = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, len_b));
         memset(INTEGER(ans), 0, sizeof(int) * len_b);
         int cmp, i = 0, j = 0;
         while (i < len_a) {
             const char *ap = CHAR(STRING_ELT(a, i));
             while (j < len_b) {
                 cmp = strncmp(ap, CHAR(STRING_ELT(b, j)), strlen(ap));
                 if (cmp > 0) {
                     j += 1;
                 } else break;
             }
             if (j == len_b)
                 break;
             if (cmp == 0)
                 INTEGER(ans)[j++] = i + 1;
             else if (cmp < 0) i += 1;
         }
         UNPROTECT(1);
         return(ans);')

    function(a, b) {
        locale = Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")
        if (locale != "C") {
            warning('temporarily trying to set LC_COLLATE to "C"')
            Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")
            on.exit(Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", locale))
        }
        a0 <- a
        lvls <- unique(a)
        a <- sort(lvls)
        o <- order(b)
        idx <- .amatch(a, b[o])[order(o)]
        f <- factor(a[idx[idx != 0]], levels=lvls)
        split(which(idx != 0), f)[a0]
    }
})
```

In comparison with this semi-friendly grep

```
f0 <- function(a, b) {
    a0 <- a
    a <- unique(a)
    names(a) <- a
    lapply(a, grep, b, fixed=TRUE)[a0]
}
```

that allows for (but doesn't pay too much of a price for) duplicate 'a' values the timings for @flodel's data set are

```
> microbenchmark(f0(a, b), f3(a, b), times=5)
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 f0(a, b) 431.03595 431.45211 432.59346 433.96036 434.87550     5
 f3(a, b)  15.70972  15.75976  15.93179  16.05184  16.06767     5
```

Unfortunately, this simple algorithm fails when one element is a prefix of another

```
> str(f0(c("a", "ab"), "abc"))
List of 2
 $ : chr "abc"
 $ : chr "abc"
> str(f3(c("a", "ab"), "abc"))
List of 2
 $ : chr "abc"
 $ : chr(0)
```

Contrary to a comment, for this data set (the random number seed needs to be specified for reproducibility)

```
set.seed(123)
categ <- c("Control", "Gr", "Or", "PMT", "P450")
genes <- paste(categ, rep(1:40, each=length(categ)), sep="_")
a0 <- paste0(genes, "_", rep(1:50, each=length(genes)), "_")
b0 <- paste0(a0, "1")
ite <- 50
lg <- 1000
b <- b0[1:lg]
a <- (a0[1:lg])[sample(seq(lg), ite)]
```

`f3()` returns the same values as `grep`

```
> identical(unname(f3(a, b)), lapply(a, grep, b, fixed=TRUE))
[1] TRUE
```

The algorithms f0 and f3 have been modified to return indexes in a named list.

Comment: @Martin Morgan actually, using the following code `categ <- c("Control", "Gr", "Or", "PMT", "P450");
genes <- paste(categ, rep(1:40, each=length(categ)), sep="_");
a0 <- paste(genes, "_", rep(1:50, each=length(genes)), "_", sep="");
b0 <- paste (a0, "1", sep="");
ite <- 50;
lg <- 1000;
b <- b0[1:lg];
a <- (a0[1:lg])[sample(seq(lg), ite)];res5 <- unlist(f3(a, b))`, the methods doesn't work. First, it returns names instead of indexes and second only a small fraction of the requests give a result. Any idea?

Comment: @LudoDuvaux see the response in the answer -- the results of f3(a, b) were identical to lapply(a, grep, b, value=TRUE, fixed=TRUE) so if there's a discrepancy it's better to be precise, e.g., a single value of a and two values of b where the result is not as expected; I modified f3 to return indexes rather than values.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Ok I get it. In my previous example (the one in the question), there was no element that was prefix of another, that why ```identical(unname(f3(a, b)), lapply(a, grep, b, fixed=TRUE))``` is ```TRUE```. In my more extensive example (see my answer below), there are many. So ```f3``` fails to return the good values many times. Not sure if ```f3``` can be fixed for that without changing it completely (BTW, I cannot be of any help for the function as I don't program in ```C```).

Comment: You need to specify a random number seed to make your data reproducible. Your data does not include 'a' values where one value (in its entirety) is a prefix of another (e.g., 'aa' in its entirety is a prefix of 'aab' and causes problems, but 'aab' and 'aac' are ok even though they share a common prefix). My best guess is that you are working in a locale (what does Sys.getlocal() report?) that causes sorting in R to be different from comparison in C; you could try Sys.setlocale(locale="C") at the start of your session. I updated my answer, but it sounds like pmatch fits your use case.